# load generator linux loadrunner

Tags: linux, testing, loadrunner

I have installed the community edition of Load Runner. I want to install the Load Generator on a Linux machine but I can not find the sh files (installer.sh for example) I read in documentation anywhere. What can happen?

Answer (score 1):

Check the "standalone components" directory. there should be a Linux iso there.
Thanks,
Lior

Comment: Where is this directory?